Blazor HealthChecks - works on my system, error on Azure App Server
I have a Blazor Interactive Server app and have set up health checks as follows:
builder.Services.AddHealthChecks()
    .AddDbContextCheck<TrackingDbContext>("App Database")
    .AddDbContextCheck<UserDbContext>("Identity Database");

app.MapHealthChecks("health", new HealthCheckOptions
{
    ResponseWriter = UIResponseWriter.WriteHealthCheckUIResponse
}).AllowAnonymous();

When I run on my system using the Visual Studio integrated app server, https://localhost:7229/health gives me JSON output with the status of each check.
When I run on this same app on Azure App Server using https://ohana.tradewindsstudios.us/health I get:
Error.
An error occurred while processing your request.
Request ID: 00-f4dd263c9fd8791cf7c9dda48954031a-09ba2674b6a1313b-00

Where do I find details on this error? And is there something I need to set in App Server to allow this to work?

Logs would tell you the exact error. If I had to guess, the most likely culprit is the database health checks.

@juunas By logs I'm guessing you don't mean my app logs. I went to the Azure dashboard logs and it has 15 choices for what to look in. Any suggestions as to which to look at?

Application logs would usually contain error details.

According to the error message you shared, we also can find the details by adding ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT.

@DavidThielen - Have you checked the LogStream.

@DavidThielen Iam able to get the JSON result even for the deployed App service.The issue might be with your DB Configuration.

To get the detailed list of the error, change the stdoutLogEnabled value to true and run the app. The log with detailed error can be seen in the C:\home\LogFiles folder.

Thank you to ajkuma who provided the way to find the answer here.

To fetch more details, you may view the Application event Logs, checkout this doc for more details: application-event-log-azure-app-service

That link provides the following steps:

In the Azure portal, open the app in App Services.
Select Diagnose and solve problems.
Select the Diagnostic Tools heading.
Under Support Tools, select the Application Events button.

And in that log it was super fast/easy to find the problem. I had a typo in my Azure Storage connection string. This is the solution to my specific question. But I think the valuable part of this answer is, when this happens, read the event log.
